# Splitting a column containing strings of unequal lengths into two columns with no delimiters

Tags: r

I'm trying to split a column in a data frame into two columns. The column I'm trying to split contains strings of unequal lengths and does not have any delimiters. This is what I'm starting with:

```
  t data1
1 1   10x
2 1   10y
3 2    1x
4 2    1y
5 3    2x
6 3    2y
```

And this is where I'd like to get to:

```
  t data1 data2
1 1    10     x
2 1    10     y
3 2     1     x
4 2     1     y
5 3     2     x
6 3     2     y
```

Comment: You might add some code to your question. This can be really helpful to answer your question. Take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

If you always have a variable number of digits followed by one character you can do as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
    t = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
    data1 = c("10x", "10y", "1x", "1y", "2x", "2y")
)

tidyr::separate(df, col = data1, into = c("data1", "data2"), sep = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution. It is idependant of the number of digits and characters. It splits the string after the first sequence of digits.

```
library(data.table)
t <- fread("t data1
1   10x
1   10y
2    1x
2    1y
3    2x
3    2y")

#create part1 and part2, using the position where numeric goes to character als splitpoint
dt[, c("part1", "part2") := tstrsplit( dt$data1, "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])", perl = TRUE )][]

#    t data1 part1 part2
# 1: 1   10x    10     x
# 2: 1   10y    10     y
# 3: 2    1x     1     x
# 4: 2    1y     1     y
# 5: 3    2x     2     x
# 6: 3    2y     2     y
```